# Image Display without onPress call

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-modal

1. I have been able to create a gallery, though I followed a tutorial to achieve it and I changed some parameters to suit what I want. The photo gallery shows when a button is pressed, but I don't want the photos to show on button press, I want to achieve the modal containing the gallery to show once the page opens. I need help to achieve it....thanks
2. When a photo is selected, I want the selected photo to take the entire screen with the share button...I have been trying to achieve that also but keep running into errors. Thanks!

```js
toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: !this.state.modalVisible})
    }

    share = () => {
        const image = this.state.photos[this.state.index].node.image.uri
        RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(image, 'base64')
        .then((data) => {
          let shareOptions = {
            title: "React Native Share Example",
            message: "Check out this photo!",
            url: `data:image/jpg;base64,${data}`,
            subject: "Check out this photo!"
          };
    
          Share.open(shareOptions)
            .then((res) => console.log('res:', res))
            .catch(err => console.log('err', err))
        })
      }

      render() {
        console.log('state :', this.state)
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
              title='View Photos'
              onPress={() => { this.toggleModal(); this.getPhotos() }}
            />
            <Modal
              animationType={"slide"}
              transparent={false}
              visible={this.state.modalVisible}
              onRequestClose={() => console.log('closed')}
            >
              <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                <Button
                  title='Close'
                  onPress={this.toggleModal}
                />
                <ScrollView
                  contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
                  {
                    this.state.photos.map((p, i) => {
                      return (
                        <TouchableHighlight
                          style={{opacity: i === this.state.index ? 0.5 : 1}}
                          key={i}
                          underlayColor='transparent'
                          onPress={() => this.setIndex(i)}
                        >
                          <Image
                            style={{
                              width: width/3,
                              height: width/3
                            }}
                            source={{uri: p.node.image.uri}}
                          />
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </ScrollView>
                {
                  this.state.index !== null  && (
                    <View style={styles.shareButton}>
                      <Button
                          title='Share'
                          onPress={this.share}
                        />
                    </View>
                  )
                }
              </View>
            </Modal>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin! Could you share a little more about the errors that you're seeing? That might help someone to be able to understand the problem more and provide good suggestions 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. So in order to toggle once the page opens you should include the 'toggleModal' call in "componentDidMount". This method is part of the component life cycle and is being called once when the component gets rendered.
2. I think the the best approach would be adding a boolean flag in the components state that indicates if it was shared or not and then you can change the photos map like this:

   ```
    this.state.photos.map((p, i) => {
        const isSelected = i === this.state.index;
        const divide = isSelected && this.share === true ? 1 : 3;
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                style={{ opacity: isSelected ? 0.5 : 1 }}
                key={i}
                underlayColor='transparent'
                onPress={() => this.setIndex(i)}
            >
                <Image
                    style={{
                        width: width / divide,
                        height: width / divide
                    }}
                    source={{ uri: p.node.image.uri }}
                />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
   })
   ```

Hopefully this is what you intended to acheive.

Comment: Thanks @D10S your answer gave me an insight to solve the problem...instead of creating a new screen/page for the the modal to show when the button is toggled to show modal of my gallery, I added the code to my camera screen.